# Возможно ли сделать рэгдолл червя если есть модель без костей? Если да, то как?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать физическую модель червя, но никак не пойму как превратить его в рэгдолл

Comment: Рэгдолл – красивая крупная кошка с роскошной густой шерстью. Она деликатна, спокойна, дружелюбна и беззаветно предана своему хозяину.

Comment: А если серьезно - то в гугле полно статей по процедурной анимации. И не важно это червь или нет. Ознакомся с тем, что там есть, а потом приходи с КОНКРЕТНЫМ вопросом. Что до модели без костей - сделать скелет червю вообще не проблема, для чего мучится с костылями в виде отсутствия костей? Можно, но для чего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует прекрасный сервис - [mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/). Там вы можете, как и наложить кости, так и "прилепить" к ним уже готовые Анимации, в самом сервисе их более 1000